# How to pass parameters to program ran in Docker container?

Tags: linux, docker, odoo

I'm new to Docker and I want to use an Odoo Docker image.
I want to update module, normally I would restart the server and start it again with

`odoo -u module_name`

But I cannot find how to do this with Docker container.
In other words, I would like to start application inside container with specific parameters.

I would like to do something like this

`docker start odoo -u module_name`

How to do it?

Comment: `docker run -p 8069:8069 --name odoo --link db:db -t odoo <param1> <param2> etc.`

Answer (score 0):

you can use docker-compose and inside Odoo service add bellow command:

```
tty: true
command: -u target_modules_to_update
```

if you don't have a docker-compose file let me know and i will help.

Comment: Thanks. I don't have docker-compose file, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

@tjwnuk you can add the following code In file named docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    image: odoo:version_number_here
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "target_port_here:8069"
    tty: true
    command: -u module_name -d database_name or any config paramter you need to add
    volumes:
      - odoo:/var/lib/odoo
      - ./config/odoo.config:/etc/odoo/odoo.conf
      - ./addons-enterprise:/mnt/enterprise-addons
      - ./custom_addons:/mnt/extra-addons
    restart: always
  db:
    image: postgres:version_number_here
    ports:
      - "1432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=db_name
      - POSTGRES_USER=db_user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=db_password
    volumes:
      - "odoo-dbs:/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata"
    restart: always
volumes:
  odoo:
  odoo-dbs:
```

And you should have those dirs:

1- config Inside this dir you should have file name odoo.config you can add any configuration here also

2- addons-enterprise <== this for enterprise addons If you have

3- custom_addons  <== this for your custom addons

finally, If you don't Install docker-compose you can run this command below:

apt install docker-compose

I hope this answer helps you and anyone who has the same case.

Answer (score -1):

Either switch into the container an start another Odoo instance:

`docker exec -ti <odoo_container> bash`

`odoo -c <path_to_config> -u my_module -d my_database --max-cron-threads=0 --stop-after-init --no-xmlrpc`

or switch into the database container and set the module to state `to upgrade`:

`docker exec -ti <database_container> psql -U <odoo_db_user> <db_name>`

`UPDATE ir_module_module set state = 'to upgrade' where name = 'my_module';`

Using the database way requires a restart of odoo.

Comment: Downvote without a comment on "why" is very helpful, thanks...